# Getting rid of foreach loop to return a single record

Tags: php, variables, foreach

This should be simple, but for me as a beginner, I am still struggling with the various View display calls.  I borrowed this foreach loop from another part of my software, and it is working correctly.  It returns values for each record on my page.  However, I only want the current record.  So, I need to get rid of the foreach loop but can't figure out how to convert this foreach loop to get only the current record.

Thanks so much for your help.

```
<?php echo $this->header_part; ?>

<div id="defaultcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">
    <?php foreach($this->challengenames as $k=>$challengename) { ?>
        <header>
            <h1>
                <div class="list">
                    <span>Welcome to </span><?php echo $challengename['partnerName']; ?><span>'s Beat Waste Challenge!</span>
                </div>
            </h1>
        </header>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<?php echo $this->footer_part; ?>
```

---

### this is the function from the controller:

```
public function yourChallengeAction(){
    //get activated challenge names and set variables
    $request = JO_Request::getInstance();
    $myChallenge=$this->getChallenge();
    $this->view->challengenames = array();
    foreach($myChallenge AS $k=>$challengename){
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['partnerName'] =    $challengename['partnerName'];
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['code'] = $challengename['code'];
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['challengeTitle'] = $challengename['challengeTitle'];
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['description'] = $challengename['description'];
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['image_url'] = $challengename['image_url'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) or use [0] as your array key.

See Also ¶

```
current() - Return the current element in an array
each() - Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor
end() - Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element
next() - Advance the internal array pointer of an array
prev() - Rewind the internal array pointer
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Digits.  I think the [0] is the easiest answer for me (I have seen it used elsewhere), but I cannot get it to work correctly. Can you tell me where in my code above to put it?

Comment: $this->challengenames[0]; should work. Alternatively reset($this->challengenames); should.

Comment: `<?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[0] ?>
        <header>
            <h1>
                <div class="list">
                    <span>Welcome to </span><?php echo $challengename['partnerName']; ?><span>'s Beat Waste Challenge!</span>
                </div>
            </h1>
        </header>`

Comment: Hey Digits,  I got your line to work (it was missing a ; at the end).  BUT, it doesn't then retain the index k, so I get no values.  Any way to rewrite this a bit so I get the correct, single record value returned depending on the index k ?  Maybe using reset() might work?  Thanks so much for any advice.